# Passing signal from view to model in MVVM with ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm implementing ReactiveCocoa 4 in an as-basic-as-possible iOS app (Swift), in order to get a better idea of how to use it with MVVM architecture. My question is: how do I get a UITextField's textSignal from the view up to the model?

What I've got here works, but it feels like this is only 50% reactive (and not too pretty in any case):

**VIEW (in viewDidLoad)**

```
originalTextField.rac_textSignal().subscribeNext{
    (next:AnyObject!) -> () in
    let text = next as! String
    self.viewModel?.originalText=text
}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
var originalText:String?{
    didSet{self.model.originalText=originalText}
}
```

**MODEL**

```
var originalText:String?{
    didSet{//Do model stuff}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I currently implement this behavior, I'm fairly new to RAC as well so take it with a grain of salt.

I'm using `ReactiveCocoa 4.1.0 & Rex 0.10.0`

---

**ViewModel**:

1. Set a `MutableProperty` for `originalText`

Mutable properties have a `producer` property that you will bind to from your view.

With that bound, calling `originalText.producer.startWithNext` will create a Signal and add 1 observer so you'll be able to receive values from within your ViewModel

```
    let originalText: MutableProperty<String> = MutableProperty("")

    func observeTextField(){
        originalText.producer.startWithNext { (str) in
            self.model.originalText = str
        }
    }
```

---

**View**:

Add [Rex](https://github.com/neilpa/Rex) as a dependency and import it. You'll be using `ignoreError` from Rex to handle a type conflict.

`SignalProducer` is defined as `SignalProducer<T, ErrorType>` so you'll have to drop the `ErrorType` to match your `MutableProperty<String>`.

1. Create a signal producer from the textfield
2. Ignore the error on the signal producer
3. Bind the signal producer to your ViewModel's `MutableProperty`
4. Call `ViewModel.observeTextField` from the the view after the binding from step 3

The infix `<~` operator binds the producer to your ViewModel's `MutableProperty`

```
    import Rex
```

...

```
    let textFieldProducer = (originalTextField.rac_textSignal()
        .toSignalProducer()
        .map {text in text as! String}
        .ignoreError())!

    viewModelInstance.originalText <~ textFieldProducer
```

---

I hope this helps you.